# How to compare one element of one array numerically to another element in another array in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and made two arrays for two tab delimited input files.I was searching for a way to compare the column(element) of one array numerically to element of another array. Is there any way to do that.My code till now is as below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from array import *
#print len(sys.argv)
if len(sys.argv) != 4:
 print 'Usage: python scores.py <infile1> <infile2> <outfile>'
 sys.exit(1)

f1 = open ("12877overlappedallvariants.gvf", "r")
f2 = open ("unmatched.12877overlappedallvariants.gvf", "r")
f3 = open ("out.txt", "w")

for line in f1.readlines():
 cols = line.split('\t')
 #print cols[5:6]


for line in f2.readlines():
 cols1 = line.split('\t')
 #print cols1[5:6]
```

I tried this below section of code but does not work

```
slice1 = cols[5:6]
slice2 = cols1[5:6]
new_list = []
for element in slice1:
 if element in slice2:
  new_list.append(element)
  print new_list
```

I am trying to see if the element 5 of array1 is equal to, greater than or less than element 5 of array2. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting that you should try to use
[the `with` statement](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example)
when opening files in Python. This is both more readable and removes the
possibility of a file being left unclosed (even when exceptions occur).

Comment: It would also be a good idea to use [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to read your files - it will handle them better and mean you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Lattyware sadly there are still many people who have to use Python 2.4 and `with` statement is not available until Python 2.5+, but that's a nice suggestion.

Comment: @DiegoNavarro I think that's a pretty rare situation. There is no reason to presume that this person is stuck on such an old version of Python.

Comment: Look at python's [sets](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). They are very well suited for membership testing and such.

Comment: @larsvegas sets are useful for that - but not element-wise comparisons

Comment: Sets are actually counter-productive here. First, the membership test was actually completely un-needed (the code shown doesn't really do what the asker is asking about at all), and the asker talks about the 'fifth' element, and sets are unordered.

Comment: Why are you importing names from the `array` module that you never use?

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that these are lists, not arrays. There is a difference.

You are overwriting `cols` every time you loop - meaning you will only get the last row of data - a list comprehension is in order here to get all the data you want, or better yet, simply don't store the data at all - do the operation you want on it.

Your main problem with the comparison is that you are taking list slices, rather than just taking the element you need. This is overcomplicating what you are trying to do.

So, as I mentioned in the comments, there are a lot of improvements you can make to your initial code - mainly the `with` statement and the `csv` module.

So first of all, use the `with` statement to open your files. We use `csv.reader()` as well, using the `"excel-tab"` dialect as it's a tab-delimited file, and `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` to tell it the values are numbers, so we don't have to convert them from strings later. Note that if only certain values are numbers, you will either need to quote all non-numeric values to use this method, or convert those values explicitly and not use it.

```
with open("file1.tsv") as file1, open("file2.tsv") as file2:
    rows = csv.reader(file2, dialect="excel-tab", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    rows1 = csv.reader(file2, dialect="excel-tab", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

To perform your check, simply do something like this (continued on from within the `with` block above):

```
    for cols, cols1 in zip(rows, rows1): #Use itertools.izip() in 2.x for efficiency.
        first = cols[4]
        second = cols1[4]

        if first < second:
            ...
        elif first == second:
            ...
        else: #first > second
            ...
```

Note the use of zip to loop over both files at once. We need to loop over the files as they return a row at a time, each row being a list of data for each column. You can then do as you please with the data. I have given an example of comparing the fifth value (note the index `4` - python is `0` indexed - that is, the first value is `0`, so the fifth is `4`).

By doing this all as we loop through the files, we ensure we don't have to create lists and store the data temporarily - which is useful if we end up working on large files.

If you needed to use that data a lot later, and wanted it as a list, you could simply make the two `rows` objects lists, by wrapping a `list()` call around the `csv.reader()`s.

Comment: Hey thanks, the problem is when i try to print the array1[5] after assigning it to first, it is not printing all the numbers.However , it does proper printing of the entire column in the code           for line in f1.readlines(): print cols[5:6].Thanks

Comment: `zip` *will create a list* for the user since the question uses python 2.  (see the print statement)

Comment: @mgilson That's why I put my comment next to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you need to be aware of -- First, after reading your files, you only have the last row stored (in a variable called 'cols' no less ;).  A loop like:

```
lines1=f1.readlines()
lines2=f2.readlines()

for f1line,f2line in zip(lines1,lines2):
    #compare here
```

Is probably more appropriate.  This will read the entire contents of both files into memory -- There are certainly ways to do this without reading that much data at once, but sometimes this is easiest.  `zip` can be a little confusing, but basically, it matches the first line from file1 with the first line from file2 and then the second lines of both files, and so on...

As noted in the comment by @Lattyware, the above is equivalent to:

```
for f1line,f2line in zip(f1,f2):
    #compare here
```

since files can be iterated over.  In python 2, that will still read/store both files at once, but in python 3 it will only yield one line from each at a time.  Finally, if you don't want to store all the contents of the files in python 2, you can use `itertools.izip`

```
import itertools
for f1line,f2line in itertools.izip(f1,f2):
    #compare here
```

which works just like `zip` except that it yields one element at a time.  The downside here is that `itertools.izip` goes away when you move to python 3...however, in this case, `2to3` should make the appropriate conversion.  (See comments for more info).

As for the comparison, that very much depends on what the file contains.  If it contains numbers, you can do it like this...

```
 for f1line,f2line in zip(lines1,lines2):
     row1=map(float,f1line.split())
     row2=map(float,f2line.split())
     #compare the 5th element
     if(row1[4]==row2[4]):
         #equal
     elif(row1[4]>row2[4]):
         ...
```

If you don't have the `map(float,...)` bit, python will do a string comparison.

python also has the [cmp function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#cmp) which might be useful if you want to compare now and use the result of the comparison later.

Comment: There is no reason to use `file.readlines()` - you can iterate directly over the file object.

Comment: @Lattyware -- You're right, but since the user is using python 2, all of the contents from both files will be stored in memory anyway.  I figured that I would stick with what the user already knows.  Anyway, I've edited to point out that readlines is indeed not necessary.

Comment: It's a bad practice. As he is using Python 2.x, you might suggest the use of `itertools.izip()` to avoid that reading into memory.

Comment: @Lattyware -- You're right, but using `itertools.izip` breaks python3 compatibility in his script.  Regardless, I've edited.  (So does the print already there...but...that's easily fixed)

Comment: @Lattyware -- It doesn't, I just tested. `RefactoringTool: No files need to be modified.` with a simple script that uses `itertools.izip`  (used `2to3-2.6` and `2to3-3.2`).

Comment: Update -- Apparently `a=itertools.izip` fails with `2to3`, but a=`itertools.izip(range(30),range(30))` is Ok.  weird.  @Lattyware

Answer (score 0):

I would write it as such:

```
import csv

file1 = csv.reader(open('name1'), delimiter='\t')
file2 = csv.reader(open('name2'), delimiter='\t')

for row1, row2 in zip(file1, file2):
    print cmp(row1[5], row2[5])
```

`

cmp returns -1 for lt, 0 for eq, or 1 for gt

**If row?[5] is numeric, then...**

```
print cmp(float(row1[5]), float(row2[5])) # or int, or any other dtype
```

Comment: This won't work - the values you are comparing will be strings

Comment: It'll work if the OP needs to compare strings *cough* - yes, but thank you - edited